# 'int org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable.getPropertyCount()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, soap, ksoap2

i know the condition when i m getting this exception when i am connected to internet but internet is not in service so that time my request goes to on server but i m not able to handle that respond.. after that i am getting this exception.

//I am getting `NullPointerException on response= envelope.getResponse();`

```
class Logintask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            setmainloader(1);

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            String NAMESPACE = "URL";
            String URL = "API Call";
            String SOAP_ACTION = "Validate user api";
            String METHOD_NAME = "Some method";

            SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);


            Request.addProperty("TokenID", sm.getUserDetails().get(SessionManager.TOKEN_ID));



            Request.addProperty("UserName", enteredusername);
            Request.addProperty("Pwd", enteredpassword);
            Request.addProperty("GCMID", " ");
            Request.addProperty("Imei", imei);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);
            HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 20000);

            try {
                httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {


                //CHECK FOR RESPONSE


                Log.d("check for response", "doInBackground: ");
```

//i am getting exception here ???? when i am getting this response when //connected no wifi or mobile data but internet is not coming.

```
            response=envelope.getResponse();



            //  Log.d("response",response.toString());

        } catch (SoapFault e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }

        return null;
    }
```

**here is my log below**

> FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #6
>                                                      Process: com.virtuzoconsultancyservicespvtltd.attendenceapp, PID: 13903
>                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing
>   doInBackground()
>                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
>                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
>                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
>                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
>                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'int org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable.getPropertyCount()' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                          at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.getResponse(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:521)
>                                                          at com.vcpl.attendenceappnew.EmailDialog$mailattendance.doInBackground(EmailDialog.java:224)
>                                                          at com.vcpl.attendenceappnew.EmailDialog$mailattendance.doInBackground(EmailDialog.java:175)
>                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
>                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
>                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
>                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
>                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
 response=envelope.getResponse();
```

to this

```
SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
```

Comment: #ironman thanks for the comment but i have already tried this thing before but m getting the same. when what ever the response is coming in this condition i can't read also. when i put the debugging point on that line app suddenly chased and got that log. i thing, _i am unable to convert this object_.

Comment: Now my issue solved, i just added one catch block for  NullPointerException    , i used only Object class for response. btw thanks.

Comment: **i get this errors....**

any solutions

java.net.UnknownHostException: host == null

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable.getPropertyCount()' on a null object reference

Comment: i solved this issue but i used ntlm authentication. so you can try on this way